# Parsing a JSON with a set of Values

Tags: jquery

I am working on parsing of a JSON .

I got the following JSON (also describs the path)

```
{
    "item": {
        "T1": [
            {
                "name": "Ice creams",
                "T2": [
                    {
                        "name": "Cone",
                        "T3": [
                            {
                                "name": "Frosty",
                                "leaf": [
                                    {
                                        "id": "53",
                                        "has_topping": "0",
                                        "price": "75",
                                        "name": "Regular Cone, Single Scoop, Vanila ",
                                        "image": "/JSON_images/icecream_cup_vanilla.jpg",
                                        "Discount": 10,
                                        "has_crust": "0"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Cup",
                        "T3": [
                            {
                                "name": "Frosty",
                                "leaf": [
                                    {
                                        "id": "59",
                                        "has_topping": "1",
                                        "price": "75",
                                        "name": "Regular Cup, Frosty 150 Ml",
                                        "image": "/JSON_images/icecream_cup_vanilla.jpg",
                                        "Discount": 10,
                                        "has_crust": "0"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Stick",
                        "T3": [
                            {
                                "name": "Frosty",
                                "leaf": [
                                    {
                                        "id": "60",
                                        "has_topping": "1",
                                        "price": "75",
                                        "name": "Regular Stick, Frosty 70 Ml",
                                        "image": "/JSON_images/icecream_cup_vanilla.jpg",
                                        "Discount": 10,
                                        "has_crust": "0"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have got an array of the path as shown

var patharray =  ["Ice creams","Stick","Frosty"] ;

How can i search the above JSON dynamically with the above path mentioned inside the patharray

So that the response for that abovepatharray would be

```
 {
    "leaf": [
        {
            "id": "60",
            "has_topping": "1",
            "price": "75",
            "name": "Regular Stick, Frosty 70 Ml",
            "image": "/JSON_images/icecream_cup_vanilla.jpg",
            "Discount": 10,
            "has_crust": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

I got a search function which works is generic (Accepts a single parameter and resturns the values )

But the issue with this is  it can't dentify the path and returns only the first found .

```
function isArray(what) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(what) === '[object Array]';
}

function isObject(what) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(what) === '[object Object]';
}

function addZeros(val) 
{
    val    = ""+val;
    return val.length === 1 ? "0"+val : val;
}

var results = [];
var cancel = false;



function recursiveSearch(name, json, startSaving, parentJson) {
    if (cancel) return;
    if (startSaving) {
        if (parentJson["leaf"]) {
            results.push("leaf");
            results.push(parentJson["leaf"]);
            cancel = true; //pushing leaf twice for somereason, work around with 'cancel'
            return;
        } else if (json["name"]) {
            results.push(json["name"]);
            return;
        } else if (json["leaf"]) {

            results.push(json["leaf"]);
            cancel = true; //pushing leaf twice for somereason, work around with 'cancel'
            return;
        }
    }
    if (isArray(json)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            recursiveSearch(name, json[i], startSaving, json);
        }
    } else {
        if (isObject(json)) {
            for (key in json) {
                if (key == "name") {
                    if (json[key] == name) {
                        startSaving = true;
                    }
                } else if (key == name) {
                    startSaving = true;
                }
                recursiveSearch(name, json[key], startSaving, json);
            }
        }
    }
}


function searchLeaf(name)
{


}

function search(name) {
    results = [];
    cancel = false;
    recursiveSearch(name, jsondata);

    return results;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you have any JSON, what you have is a javascript object !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assumption or what I have understood from the question** - Elements position in patharray are according to the search path

means - `"iceCream" -> "Stick" -> "Frosty"`

```
var patharray = ["Ice creams","Stick","Frosty"] ;

function findElement(obj, patharray, index) {
    var res = '';
    if(index < patharray.length) {
        var searchStr = patharray[index];
        index++;
        for(each in obj) {
            if(obj[each] instanceof Array) {
                var found = false;
                for(var i=0;i<obj[each].length;i++) {
                    if(obj[each][i].name == searchStr) {
                        res = obj[each][i];
                        if(index<patharray.length) {
                            console.log('search again')
                            res = findElement(obj[each][i], patharray, index);
                        }
                        found = true
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(found) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }   
        return res
    }
}
var patharray = ["Ice creams","Stick","Frosty"] ;
console.log(findElement(k.item, patharray, 0), 'found');

//output
Object {name: "Frosty", leaf: Array[1]}
    leaf: Array[1]
        0: Object
            Discount: 10
            has_crust: "0"
            has_topping: "1"
            id: "60"
            image: "/JSON_images/icecream_cup_vanilla.jpg"
            name: "Regular Stick, Frosty 70 Ml"
            price: "75"
        length: 1
    name: "Frosty"
```

Comment: Hi Harpreet , could you please let me know how can i test this ?? I mean what is k.item in this case ??

Comment: Your complete object is **K** and **0** is starting index of search item from pathArray. In this case it would refer to IceCream